# What is this pipe I found buried under my yard?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, backyard

I have been living in this house for 3 years. The house was build in 1957.

While digging in the yard to prepare to install pavers, I came across a black pipe that I don't know what it is. I'm following the pipe to see where it leads but I don't want to continue to destroy the yard in the process. I dug it for 12 feet already. It is about two feet deep. There's a section that has a clamp that says "ARUNDALE MFRS" Couldn't find anything online.

Does any one knows what this pipe is used for?
Thanks in advance.

Second pic also shows a discovered old sprinkler line. It is not the same type of material
[image: black pipe]

[image: dug so far]

Comment: Arundale Mfrs made pipe clamps but that's not much help. What's the pipe made of? Metal or plastic or a coating? Is it bendy or stiff?

Comment: Why are you worried about whats 2 ft deep ?  My advice is to leave it alone.  The last thing you want is to puncture it or crack it.

Comment: Roughly what size is this mystery pipe?

Comment: Did you call whatever the local equivalent of Dig-Safe is before you started excavating? If it's a utility right of way passing through, you can get in a world of trouble. If it's connected to your house that should disambiguate what it is pretty quickly.

Comment: @DJ. - The pipe looks like it is made out of rubber it is bendy.

Comment: @RohitGupta  - Thanks. Just want to know what it was used for and If I can still use it.

Comment: @brhans - it is a one inch.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - That's a good point I didn't follow before digging.  I did called the city yesterday to get original plans drawings of the property to see if that is listed there.

Comment: @RamonSuero, please answer the question ins teh comments by editing your post.  It makes your question complete.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like (since you don't specify what it is or even what it feels like) black foam insulation which I'd associate most commonly with a refrigerant line, (For air conditioning, heat pump, or walk-in refrigerator/freezer) though it's unusual for such a line to be buried 2 feet deep in the yard.

The way it bulges out between the clamps is highly suggestive of foam insulation.

The surface texture and use of clamps are not congruent with the worst type of black pipe to find in your yard, "Orangeburg" sewer pipe made from tarpaper. No size reference is given, but it also *seems* like it's smaller than that would be, lacking a reference.